# php . json_encode()

Tags: php

При использовании json_encode,возникла ситуация когда вторым параметром нужно передать JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE , и JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES одновременно.

То есть json_encode($typeArray ,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); -вот так работает.
Вот так тоже json_encode($typeArray ,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

Но нужно одновременно чтоб было и JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE и JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES;

Comment: `json_encode($typeArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Comment: Спасибо. Напиши в ответ я плюсану, Чот в манулах рылся такого не увидел.

Comment: В мануалах написано, что flags это битовая маска, а дальше видимо подразумевается, что читатель знает, [что такое битовая маска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) и как с ней работать